# How to commit a non-subversioned file into a repository?

Tags: svn, repository

The environment: SVN, Netbeans, Hudson

SVN Project A: Builds a library file (foo.jar). The build file is under /dist, which is ignored for svn, the sourcecode is under svn control.

SVN Project B: holds all library files. (other SVN projects get all their libraries from here via external svn)

Question: I want to commit foo.jar from A into B. How to do that ? foo.jar cannot be added or committed because it is not under SVN control.

Thanks for any hints ! (The question is independent from the IDE and CI Server)

Comment: If you are hosting the file on a remote server so that lots of people can all access the repository, then I don't think what you are trying to do really makes sense. Project A is creating a specfic library of code, foo.jar, correct? and project B is pooling all these libraries together, foo.jar, bar.jar foobar.jar etc etc. why DONT you want version control? and why not just access from project A if you want foo.jar?

Comment: I suspect it is because project B has the output files from many different projects, including project A.  Many teams may need to get these artifacts, but have no use for the source that generated them.  Having a central repository for all such libraries may make sense in a case like that.

Comment: we have a number of web projects with custom libraries. I need to ensure all use the same libraries, so i pull them in via svn external. (And I dont want everyone to have accessto he lib sources).

Comment: But if project B is just pooling this libs, why not use SVN, then people can ensure they have the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more clever way to do it, but what if your final step in the build process was to copy the output file (foo.jar) from projA/dist into projB/lib, and then check in projB?

This would assume that the two working copies are checked out in a specific place on the machine(s) used to perform builds, which may not be ideal from an academic standpoint of allowing the projects to be checked out anywhere, and have no interdependencies, but it should meet your needs to get the job done and move to the next problem!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change your build in that it automatically copies your jar to project B and when you commit project B it automatically commits your jar ? Is this an acceptable approach ?

Answer (score 0):

When we need to do something like this we usually copy the file from A to B automatically at the end of the build. You could probably change the build process to commit it automatically if everything was fine (though that's not always a good idea).